# Trying to compare a value to multiple, multiple dimension arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, comparison

I have a spreadsheet of data in multiple columns. In VBA, I am trying to set a value in each row depending on the data in any one of three of the other columns. It will always be an OR comparison between those data and will need to return one of five values.

So I have created five arrays (they are multidimensional due to reading them in as ranges, however, they could be one dimensional if needed, I suppose), and I was going to compare the three columns to those arrays using a bunch of IF-THEN statements to return the necessary value.

Creating the arrays was easy enough, but I have no idea how to create the IF-THEN process correctly. An example of the process would be something like:

```
IF A1 is in ArrayA THEN

 D1="Dog"

ELSEIF A1 is in ArrayB THEN

 D1="Cat"

ELSEIF B1 is in ArrayC THEN

 D1="Bird"

ELSEIF B1 is in ArrayD THEN

 D1="Monkey"

ELSEIF C1 is in ArrayE THEN

 D1="Blue"

ELSE

 D1="Other"
```

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to accomplish what I am trying to do, so I am definitely open to suggestions for a different approach. Thank you.

Comment: is d1 the column ref in the 2d array? e.g. D1 = E is column E?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. No. E is just the value I would put in column D if the value in column C was in ArrayE. I will try to make it a little clearer.

Comment: Ok, so I am new to Stackoverflow, so I might not understand everything. Someone just posted an answer to my question above and I was able to get it to work for my purposes. However, that post is no longer there. Does that mean the person deleted it?

Comment: Normally yes, either that or a moderator deleted it for one reason or another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is how I got it working. Most of this came from another person, but they deleted their comment so I can't thank them.

```
arrCols = Array(arrA, arrB, arrC, arrD, arrE)
arrVals = Array("Dog", "Cat", "Bird", "Monkey", "Blue")
For i = 2 To rCnt
    pID = Cells(i, 2).Value
    pName = Cells(i, 3).Value
    pGroup = Cells(i, 4).Value
    ans = ""
    For j = LBound(arrCols) To UBound(arrCols)
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(pGroup, arrCols(j), 0)) Then
            ans = arrVals(j)
            Exit For
        ElseIf Not IsError(Application.Match(pName, arrCols(j), 0)) Then
            ans = arrVals(j)
            Exit For
        ElseIf Not IsError(Application.Match(pID, arrCols(j), 0)) Then
            ans = arrVals(j)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
 Cells(i, 5) = IIf(ans = "", "Other", ans)
 Next i
```

I created an array of arrays to search through. The i loop cycles through all rows. The j loop cycles through the arrays within the main array. The three IF statements are needed for checking the three different columns. The returned value is defaulted to "Other" unless it is found in one of the arrays.

The only thing I was able to add to this code was the stuff needed to check three different columns in the row.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do it without looping

```
If Len("," & Join(ArrayA, ",") & ",") <> Len("," & Replace(Join(ArrayA, ","), "," & Range("A1").Value & ",", "") & ",") Then
    Range("D1").Formula = "Dog"
ElseIf Len("," & Join(ArrayB, ",") & ",") <> Len("," & Replace(Join(ArrayB, ","), "," & Range("A1").Value & ",", "") & ",") Then
    Range("D1").Formula = "Cat"
ElseIf Len("," & Join(ArrayC, ",") & ",") <> Len("," & Replace(Join(ArrayC, ","), "," & Range("A1").Value & ",", "") & ",") Then
    Range("D1").Formula = "Bird"
ElseIf Len("," & Join(ArrayD, ",") & ",") <> Len("," & Replace(Join(ArrayD, ","), "," & Range("A1").Value & ",", "") & ",") Then
    Range("D1").Formula = "Monkey"
ElseIf Len("," & Join(ArrayE, ",") & ",") <> Len("," & Replace(Join(ArrayE, ","), "," & Range("A1").Value & ",", "") & ",") Then
    Range("D1").Formula = "Blue"
Else
    Range("D1").Formula = "Other"
End If
```

Join the array to a string then check the len against the len of the string with the keyword (Range("A1")) replaced with nothing. Put a comma on either side to make sure it is the full word (Don't want something like Catfish to return as a Cat)

And the same thing using InStr instead:

```
If InStr(1, "," & Join(ArrayA, ",") & ",", Range("A1").Value) > 0 Then
    Range("D1").Formula = "Dog"
ElseIf InStr(1, "," & Join(ArrayB, ",") & ",", Range("A1").Value) > 0 Then
    Range("D1").Formula = "Cat"
ElseIf InStr(1, "," & Join(ArrayC, ",") & ",", Range("A1").Value) > 0 Then
    Range("D1").Formula = "Bird"
ElseIf InStr(1, "," & Join(ArrayD, ",") & ",", Range("A1").Value) > 0 Then
    Range("D1").Formula = "Monkey"
ElseIf InStr(1, "," & Join(ArrayE, ",") & ",", Range("A1").Value) > 0 Then
    Range("D1").Formula = "Blue"
Else
    Range("D1").Formula = "Other"
End If
```

Comment: I am assuming the above code still only checks against the A column? Would I have to copy all of this code three times to compare columns A, B, and C to each array?